# Existence of a series whose partial sums are bounded and $\lim_{k \to \infty} b_k = 0$, but does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis

Existence of a series whose partial sums are bounded and $\lim_{k \to \infty} b_k = 0$, but does not converge?

Can one design such a series? Any ideas? Starting with the harmonic series, I reached nowhere. Again, the series is divergent, but some of the partial sums converge.

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  What is $b_k$?

Comment: @L.F., the partial sums of the harmonic series are not bounded.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh I missed that bit.

Comment: Slightly more generally, it is not difficult to construct a piecewise constant function $f$ on $[0,+\infty)$ which tends to $0$ at $+\infty$, such that the antiderivative $\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is bounded, and yet the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty}f(t)dt$ diverges. Turning back to series, this yields sos440's example. Of course, this example can be made smooth.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an easy example:

$$(b_n) = \Big(\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}}, \underbrace{\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2^2}, \cdots, \frac{1}{2^2}}}_{2^2\text{-terms}}, \underbrace{\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2^3}, \cdots, -\frac{1}{2^3}}}_{2^3\text{-terms}}, \cdots \Big). $$

Its partial sum is bounded in $[0, 1]$ and the general term vanishes as $n\to\infty$, but nevertheless its sum does not converge.

Comment: If the partial sums are bounded, does it mean they converge? Also, is there a subsequence of the partial sum that converges? Moreover, if you'd kindly explain the motivation behind the construction of the example, it will be helpful to understand.

Comment: The partial sums do not converge, they go up to one, down to zero, up to one, down to zero, forever. Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the harmonic series is a good idea. Take as many terms as you need to get the sum over 17. Then take the negatives of as many terms as you need to get the sum down to $-42$. Then take positive terms to get back up to $17$, negatives to get to $-42$, etc., ad infinitum.

Comment: Why 17 and -42? Would you mind writing out the series and the motivating behind the reasoning?

Comment: $17$ is the most random number, and $42$ is the answer to life, the Universe, and everything. Look, you take $$1\pm(1/2)\pm(1/3)\pm\cdots$$ and you keep taking plus signs until you get to [insert your favorite positive number here], then take minus signs until you get to [insert your favorite number among numbers smaller than your favorite number here], then take plus signs up to your first number, minus signs down to your second number, and so on, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Even if 42 is the answer to life, it helps to state that. Sometimes, things are not that obvious.

Comment: Allusions aren't allusions if you cite your source.

Comment: I thought we are here to do quite the opposite of allusion, innit? I am trying to understand the darn thing, not enjoy a magic trick.

Comment: Personally, I'm here to help (or make) people think. Some go along with this program more readily than others. I'm convinced you will learn more by thinking about things I write than by having me spoonfeed you every step of the way. I could be wrong.